# rx java retrofit 2 error handling

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using retrofit 2 along with rx java

Situation: 
the app sends some request, then i get the response in json-format that is automatically converted to User dto, then in onNext method of rx java i receive the list of Users. What if i get some message from server like this: {"error":"can't get the list of users"}

how to handle this situation with retrofit 2 and rx?

```
      Subscription subscriptionBranches = model.getRepoBranches(owner, name)
                    .map(branchesMapper)
                    .subscribe(new Observer<List<Branch>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {
                            ;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            if (e instanceof retrofit.HttpException) {
                                HttpException exception = (HttpException) e;
                            }
                            showError(e);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(List<Branch> list) {
                            branchList = list;
                            view.showBranches(list);
                        }
                    });

            addSubscription(subscriptionBranches);
.....
    @Override
    public Observable<List<RepositoryDTO>> getRepoList(String name) {
        return apiInterface
                .getRepositories(name)
                .compose(applySchedulers());
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33977686/retrofit-2-0-rxjava-error-json-body/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Depending on the server response you might or might not get into your `onError` function. If the server returns a non-2XX http status code you'll get into the `onError` method. If on the other hand you get a 2XX http status code you'll enter `onNext`.

I'm assuming you can deal with the `onNext` bit and I'll explain how you can do it in the `onError`. It's important to realise that there are many ways of doing this and this is just an example that uses **okhttp 3** and **retrofit 2 beta4**.

So retrofit2 says that every non-2XX http responses are `HttpException`s when using `rxjava`. This you already have it there in your code:

```
if (e instanceof retrofit.HttpException) {
   HttpException exception = (HttpException) e;
}
```

Now what you want to do is get the body of the response. This you can achieve by calling `Response response = exception.response()` in the `HttpException` you have there. With the response, getting the error body is quite straight forward. You just call `response.errorBody()`. You can then convert the body to a java object or just access it as a string.

Since you have a `json` error body as an example, here's how you can convert the response body to a java object:

```
new GsonConverterFactory().responseBodyConverter(type,
      new Annotation[0]).convert(response.errorBody());
```

where `type` is the class of the java object that represents the error.

So putting it all together, on your `onError` method you could write something like:

```
if (e instanceof retrofit.HttpException) {
   HttpException exception = (HttpException) e;
   Response response = exception.response();
   Converter<ResponseBody, MyError> converter = new GsonConverterFactory()
       .responseBodyConverter(MyError.class, Annotation[0]);
   MyError error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
}
```

`MyError` is a model that represents the error json you have in your question.

Comment: thanks man, cool way. I implemented it a little bit differently using Result<List<RepositoryDTO>>, then  i just converted the responseBodyResponse.response().errorBody().byteStream() to object using gson. Your way is actually better than mine.

Comment: @Fred good answer! Can you check this similar question, but in my case to handle 2xx http codes:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047055/retrofit-2-rxandroid-handle-errors-4xx-and-some-200

Comment: Annotation? What is this?

Comment: @SaifulAzad I'm afraid I don't get your comment. Could you be more specific pls? Which annotation are you referring to?

Comment: Ah. Thank for your reply although you were afraid. BTW, I have solved it. Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in the case you mentioned you will just enter into your `onError` handling, because retrofit will fail to deserialize your response, as it's not formatted as a `List`. You could potentially handle your case through that based off of the exception type.

If you can't alter the api to return consistent response types, you will have to look into using [TypedInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377633/retrofit-and-typedinput#31377817), and possibly a converter.

Additionally, while it may not be completely relevant/overkill to the situation at hand, [TypeAdapters](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) bear mentioning. They'll let you determine how `retrofit` deserializes `gson` on a per class basis.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(MyClass.class, new MyAdapter())
    .create();

RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation and the way I could get the json from the server when an error occurs was something like this:

```
retrofit2.Response<TokenRefresh> r = call.execute();

String errorMessage = "";
try {
    errorMessage = r.errorBody().string();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Timber.d("errorMessage: " + errorMessage);
```