# Retrofit 2: How to handle dynamic response

Tags: dynamic, retrofit2, pojo

I am trying fetch data from this api: http://www.omdbapi.com/
I am using Retrofit 2 and created a pojo for first json. The thing I am curious about is how to convert my pojo to second one when data is not available.

When there is data available, It returns this json:

http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Suits

```
{
Title: "Suits",
Year: "2011–",
Rated: "TV-14",
Released: "23 Jun 2011",
Runtime: "44 min",
Genre: "Comedy, Drama",
Director: "N/A",
Writer: "Aaron Korsh",
Actors: "Gabriel Macht, Patrick J. Adams, Rick Hoffman, Meghan Markle",
Plot: "On the run from a drug deal gone bad, Mike Ross, a brilliant college-dropout, finds himself a job working with Harvey Specter, one of New York City's best lawyers.",
Language: "English",
Country: "USA",
Awards: "7 nominations.",
Poster: "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk1MjYzOTU2Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzAxMTg5MTE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
Metascore: "N/A",
imdbRating: "8.7",
imdbVotes: "244,979",
imdbID: "tt1632701",
Type: "series",
totalSeasons: "6",
Response: "True"
}
```

When there is no data avilable, it returns this json:

http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=asdasdas

```
{
Response: "False",
Error: "Movie not found!"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options. Out of my head the simplest one is to include the `Error` field in the original pojo and always check for the field `Response`. When this is "True" than all the other fields will be present. When "False", only the `Error` field will be there.

Another option and perhaps the least flexible and understandable is to have a pojo `Error` from where you can inherit. You'd still have to inspect the value of `Response` to check if there's an error. I personally would avoid this option here, but I thought it's good to know you can still do it. Something like this:

```
class Error {
  @SerializedName("Error")
  @Expose
  private String error;
  // ...
}

class Movie extends Error {
  // other fields here
}
```

As you can see this is pretty ugly, but works...

A third option you can try is to check the Http status code. This one depends on the API. If the api returns Http code 200 even when there's an error, then this is not that straight forward. However it's my favourite since it provides more correctness in my opinion.

Say the api return Http 404 when there's no data. You can then check this status and use a different pojo to deserialise the error body (The pojo could simply be the error message). If you're using retrofit with the built in `Callbacks` you'd have to do this on `onResponse`. If you're using `RxJava`, then this is even more straight forward as you can do it easily in the `onError` method (All non-2XX http responses land in the `onError` method).

You can access the error body of a retrofit response with [errorBody](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#errorBody--). You can convert it to a pojo using `Gson` or simply using this snippet:

```
Converter<ResponseBody, MyError> converter = new GsonConverterFactory()
   .responseBodyConverter(MyError.class, Annotation[0]);
MyError error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
```

(Here `MyError` would be the name of the pojo containing the error fields).

You might want to create the converter factory only once. Most probably should be the one you used when creating the `Retrofit` instance.

If you're actually using `RxJava` you can check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36329213/344487) on how to access the error body in an Rx response

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, Fred. =) I went with the second option. I created a Status model which contains response and error fields then extended my first model with Status.

Comment: Glad I could help