# How to handle errors with Retrofit?

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

My server returns a basic JSON structure for all request like:

```
{  
    "success": false,
    "data": {  
        "errors": {  
            "email": [  
                "This is not an email."
            ],
            "password": [  
                "The password must be at least 6 characters."
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Where `success` can be true or false, and data can return a number of things, from `errors` to data the app might need.

**How can I handle this response (both success and error) using Retrofit?**

What would need to be changed/added to my Retrofit API call?

```
Call<BasicResponse> call = apiService.login(emailString, passwordString);
call.enqueue(new Callback<BasicResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<BasicResponse> call, Response<BasicResponse> response) {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<BasicResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        //
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you'll want to work with your models. You have a couple of options here, but in the end it comes down to the response code of your api and how you structure your models.

Let's get the models out of the way first. One way you can deal with the object having an error or not is by including this as a field of your models. Say you have the error object:

```
public class Errors {
  // ...
}
```

This represents the errors object in your json:

```
"errors": {  
        "email": [  
            "This is not an email."
        ],
        "password": [  
            "The password must be at least 6 characters."
        ]
    }
```

Now say you have a data object to represent the json object:

```
"data": {  
    "errors": {  
        "email": [  
            "This is not an email."
        ],
        "password": [  
            "The password must be at least 6 characters."
        ]
    }
}
```

You can simply have:

```
public class Data {
   @SerializedName("success")
   @Expose
   private boolean success;
   @SerializedName("errors")
   @Expose
   private Errors errors;
   // Here you can then add other models, i.e:
   // @SerializedName("user")
   // @Expose
   // private User user;
 }
```

As you can see, you can then add the rest of the models to the `Data` object. When the response is successful, `errors` will be null and `success` true. When the response is unsuccessful you'll have the opposite scenario. You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39688319/retrofit-2-how-to-handle-dynamic-response/39698434#39698434) for more details and other ways to achieve this.

Now to the part where you handle the error response.

If your call succeeds you'll end up in the `onResponse` call. This means that you'll have to check the value of `Data.success` before you can start interacting with your objects. If `false` you know you can access the `errors` field without producing a `NullPointerException` and if `true` you know you have the data correctly retrieved.

`onFailure` is only called when there's an exception in example socket timeout or serialising and deserialising the request.

Comment: What error codes are accepted by the `onFailure` callback? Right now, my server responds with `400` if there was an error, but that's handled in the `onResponse` callback.

Comment: My apologies, I was under the impression that retrofit would call the ``onFailure`` for every non-2xx http status, but it actually calls the ``onResponse``. It does this for all status codes since they actually succeed in making the call. I'll edit my answer.