# Retrofit2: Custom response format for errors of failed requests

Tags: android, http, error-handling, retrofit2

I use retrofit to do http calls. On response sometimes it may happen that error occurs during server calls and I want to catch error responses in specified format.
However I should define expected response type like this `Call<Status> change(String status);`. How can I receive something like `ErrorDetails` on failed http calss in retrofit?

**P.S.** I should notice that error that I speak are those that server send error details in special format that is already agreed between android client and server.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39698434/3364266